# Ardunio UNO solve multiple overlapping timer loops

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

I'm stuck in writing two overlapping loops for switching a pump relay. If the timer "delayPump" ends (LOW) the timer "runnningPump" (HIGH) should start.

i guess some math madness, to be honest this loop is already making me mad, cause it should be easy!!!!

Any clue??

```
#define pumpSwitch_1 8
int delayPump = 10000; //delay time
int runnningPump = 5000; // running Timer
bool pumpState = LOW; 
unsigned long TimerPump = 0;
unsigned long TimerDelay = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pumpSwitch_1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pumpSwitch_1, LOW);

  TimerPump = millis();
  TimerDelay = millis(); 
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(pumpSwitch_1, pumpState);

  if (pumpState == HIGH){
    if((millis() - TimerPump) >= runnningPump){
      pumpState = LOW;
      TimerPump = millis() + delayPump;
      }
  }else {
    if((millis() - TimerDelay) >= delayPump){
      pumpState = HIGH;
      TimerDelay = millis() + runnningPump;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you wanna do this: set pin `8` to `LOW` then after `10s` toggle it to `HIGH` and then after `5s` toggle it again to `LOW`... repeat this cycle?? I don't get what you are trying to refer using *overlapping loops*.

Comment: yes! (the timer can vary up to hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

You just need a single `Timer` variable, and each time you toggle the state, set it to current time, i.e. `millis()`.

```
#define pumpSwitch_1 8
int delayPump = 10000; //delay time
int runnningPump = 5000; // running Timer
bool pumpState = LOW; 
unsigned long Timer = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pumpSwitch_1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pumpSwitch_1, LOW);

  Timer = millis();
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(pumpSwitch_1, pumpState);

  if (pumpState == HIGH) {
    if ((millis() - Timer) >= runnningPump) {
        pumpState = LOW;
        Timer = millis();
    }
  } else {
    if ((millis() - Timer) >= delayPump) {
        pumpState = HIGH;
        Timer = millis();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that was easy...using the same timer. Thx brc-dd!!!

Comment: @DisturbeD2203 **that was easy...** -- Well I won't say otherwise! You yourself had mentioned that in you question! :) I would recommend don't over-complicate simple things! You should have done this using just `delay()` function inside `if-else` of `loop`. No need of checking condition `(millis() - Timer) >= xyz;`

Comment: jajaja! delay() doesn't work, cause there are several loops running by side (https://github.com/andres2203/StadtFarm).

Comment: @DisturbeD2203 Okay removed that part from the answer! :) Good luck working on your project! ;)